# Adobe CEP extension(indesign) : Is it possible to call "js" function from "jsx"?

Tags: javascript, html, extendscript

Is it possible to call **"js"** function from **"jsx"**. without evalscript("callJsx",callbackfromjsx).
because i want to call js function, when new document are loaded using "afternew" event.

```
app.addEventListener("afterNew", myDisplayEventType);

function myDisplayEventType(myEvent){
   alert("This event is the " + myEvent.eventType + " event.");
   //here I want to call js
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do it using plugplugobject and include vulcan.js in html file relaed to js file

```
var externalObjectName = "PlugPlugExternalObject";
mylib = new ExternalObject( "lib:" + externalObjectName);
var eventObj = new CSXSEvent(); 
eventObj.type="EventName";
eventObj.data="data for event"; 
eventObj.dispatch();
```

add this code to jsx and add  event listener for  'EventName' in js file using csInterface.addeventlistener()